# Use numpy is_busday function on a date column on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I load my Excel file to a Pandas Dataframe, there are dates column on the Excel files.
after loaded, I convert the date column to a datetime64[ns]

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I created a new column on the Dataframe called  "Is_Business_Day"
On this column, I applied the is_busday from Numpy to see if the date is a weekday or weekend

I tried both codes but didn't work

```
df['Is_Business_Day']= [np.is_busday(np.datetime64(x)) for x in df['Date']]
```

and

```
df['Is_Business_Day']= [np.is_busday(x) for x in df['Date']]
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Tried to look around for the solution but can't find anything. 
Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1:

Convert `df['Date']` to string before giving it to `np.is_busday`:

```
df['Is_Business_Day'] = [np.is_busday(x) for x in df['Date'].astype(str)]
```

## Method 2:

You could just use `pandas` instead of `numpy`, and check if `Date` is in the range of business days from your minimum date to your maximum date:

```
bus_days = pd.bdate_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())

df['Is_Business_Day'] = df['Date'].isin(bus_days)
```

## Examples:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today'), pd.to_datetime('2018-09-15'))})
>>> df
         Date
0  2018-08-29
1  2018-08-30
2  2018-08-31
3  2018-09-01
4  2018-09-02
5  2018-09-03
6  2018-09-04
7  2018-09-05
8  2018-09-06
9  2018-09-07
10 2018-09-08
11 2018-09-09
12 2018-09-10
13 2018-09-11
14 2018-09-12
15 2018-09-13
16 2018-09-14
17 2018-09-15
```

You can do:

**Method 1**:

```
>>> df['Is_Business_Day'] = [np.is_busday(x) for x in df['Date'].astype(str)]
>>> df
         Date  Is_Business_Day
0  2018-08-29             True
1  2018-08-30             True
2  2018-08-31             True
3  2018-09-01            False
4  2018-09-02            False
5  2018-09-03             True
6  2018-09-04             True
7  2018-09-05             True
8  2018-09-06             True
9  2018-09-07             True
10 2018-09-08            False
11 2018-09-09            False
12 2018-09-10             True
13 2018-09-11             True
14 2018-09-12             True
15 2018-09-13             True
16 2018-09-14             True
17 2018-09-15            False
```

**Method 2**:

```
>>> bus_days = pd.bdate_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())
>>> df['Is_Business_Day'] = df['Date'].isin(bus_days)
>>> df
         Date  Is_Business_Day
0  2018-08-29             True
1  2018-08-30             True
2  2018-08-31             True
3  2018-09-01            False
4  2018-09-02            False
5  2018-09-03             True
6  2018-09-04             True
7  2018-09-05             True
8  2018-09-06             True
9  2018-09-07             True
10 2018-09-08            False
11 2018-09-09            False
12 2018-09-10             True
13 2018-09-11             True
14 2018-09-12             True
15 2018-09-13             True
16 2018-09-14             True
17 2018-09-15            False
```

Comment: converting day to string does the trick with numpy. I wonder how come that numpy function doesn't work with that pandas datetime type. I printed the dtype of the dataframe and it shows the date type is correct datetime64[ns]

Comment: Yeah, It's a bit unexpected, but I've noticed some other times that `numpy` datetimes don't play as well as they should with `pandas` datetimes...